# how to change the url which is having parameter with htacccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am passing and `id` with the PHP file name and I want to hide the URL.

**news-event-listing.php** in this page I am passing some `id` to my next page

```
<div class="date-wrap">

             <label><?php echo $res['publisheddate'] ?></label>
           <a href="news-inner.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" class="read-more-btn">Read More <i class="ms-2 bi bi-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
```

For the URL like http://localhost/glc_css/news-inner.php?id=6, I want to hide this `news-inner.php?id=6`   to something else, like:

```
localhost/glc_css/news-inner.php?id=6 => localhost/glc_css/service/6
```

What I have tried in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]



#RewriteRule ^ABOUT  about.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^CONTACT  contact.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^PRODUCT  product.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^service/([^/\.]+)?$ /news-inner.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Or https://pastebin.com/x0gd5pqB Please try both options one by one.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qa6hR1SK